# Restrict user to run shell script except which is defined in sudoer file

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I have scientific linux 6.4 running on my system, I have restricted other users to run shell script except one, which is defined in `/etc/sudoers` file.

For example:

I have one `file.sh` in my admin's `home` directory, so I wish admin to run `file.sh` only, not other shell script from anywhere in system location.

So how to achieve this?

Comment: So youre saying you want admin to be incapable of executing any script but the one? Or is that vice versa? If the former you can just set it as admin's login shell with `chsh` maybe or in `/etc/passwd` and exec it in a `chroot` or something. If the latter you probably want to `chmod` the file.

Comment: I mean to say, files which is defined in /etc/sudoer file only should be run by admin not others. @mikeserv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html

> username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /some/random/command

should allow *username* to run /some/random/command as any other user (including root) from any host. No one but *username* would be able to run that command if that is the only rule in the file.

Make sure there's not another rule that says "user" or "group" can run anything.

> %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

is pretty common and lets members of the sudo user group run any command they please.

To my knowledge there is no rule for "let someone run everything **except** /some/command. But I could be wrong. However, if your trying to do that then your probably approaching a security issue the wrong way.

Comment: Also be VERY VERY careful. The way your doing this is very dangerious. Some one could edit /some/random/command and execute anything they want, including `rm / -rf` or worse.